# Why is this MySQL query correct?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has only 3 columns. When I type the following query

```
select * from MyTable order by 5 and 2;
```

I get every thing in the table( The result is equal to that of `select * from MyTable;` ). What I originally expected is that I would get some kind of error. But I didn't get it, why?

Comment: it is discouraged to use this because column order may change

Comment: The answer seems to be "we don't know!" But it seems as if, where AND is used, the ORDER BY clause is simply being ignored.

Comment: @Strawberry I think I do, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah - sounds plausible, although I don't quite get it.

Comment: I get confused again. "select * from MyTable order by true;", and "select * from MyTable order by 5 and 0;" all return everything in the table. but "select * from MyTable order by false;" returns an error saying "Unknown column 'FALSE' in 'order clause'". How do I explain this phenomenon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happenning here is that `5 and 2` is seen as an expression which is evaluated to 1. However, it shouldn't give a result sorted by first column.

Actually, I think you only get sorted data because you inserted it in sorted sequence. Take a look at this SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e04e/1

The data is not sorted by `any of the columns`, it is being sorted by a `value 1`.

Comment: I do not think this is the case, try your own fiddle with `select * from my_tab order by 500;` and it will give you an error

Comment: @MatteoTassinari You are wrong.. when you say only 500, it is treated as a position of a column by which sorting should be done. When you say 5 and 2, then **sorting is done by whatever value is returned by the expression**. Example: when have a `TIME` column, you can sort by `ORDER BY hour(time_col)`.

Comment: You are right. It does not sort according to the 1st column. I inserted the values in sorted sequence.
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56f98/1

Comment: I get confused again. "select * from MyTable order by true;", and  "select * from MyTable order by 5 and 0;" all return everything in the table. but "select * from MyTable order by false;" returns an error saying "Unknown column 'FALSE' in 'order clause'". How can I explain this phenomenon？

Answer (score 6):

`order by 5 and 2` is interpreted as `order by (5 and 2)` which is a constant expression, hence no real ordering is done and data is simply shown in the order it was inserted.

Comment: Then he should be using commas instead of and to order by 5 and then 2

Comment: I think I understand it. (5 and 2) == (true AND true) == (1 AND 1) == 1. thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @lyen This is not the case, the data is sorted by a value 1, not by the values from first column - check my answer and the SQLFiddle example I have provided.

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej I proved your fiddle wrong: try your own fiddle with `select * from my_tab order by 500;` and it will give you an error

Comment: @MatteoTassinari you mix up sorting by providing a number of a column by which sorting should be done and sorting by a value of an expression, check my other comment.

Comment: @lyen update my answer, it would seem I wasn't right at first

Answer (score 1):

5 and 2 are column indexes and they mean 5th column and 2nd column.

Comment: But the returned data are ordered by the 1st column. How to explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from MyTable order by 5,2; 
It means start with index 5 and bring 2record i.e 5,6,7
```

Comment: But MyTable has only 3 columns, which means the 5th, 6th, and 7th columns do not exist. Why didn't I get an error message?

Comment: When you use numeric value(column no. ) with order by it does not through any error if the mention column no. does not exist. It through error only when the given column name is not exist.

Comment: Order by with numeric value(column no.) doesn't return any error when any mention column no. doesn't exist. It through error only when the given column name doesn't exist.  so, select * from MyTable order by 5,2;  with work fine but select * from MyTable order by non_existing_column_name; will through an error.